# iOS russian Localizable strings are not working (but others do)

Tags: ios, xcode, string, localization

I have already released an iOS application that is localized in english and greek using Localizable.string files, and they work as expected. The problem is that I need to add russian to my translations, and I can't. I have the entire file translated as pdf file from a native russian translator. I generated a new strings file by going into Xcode, selected my Localizable.strings package (which contains 2 files, one for Greek and one for English), and on the right pane, I clicked '+' in the Localization section, and I selected Russian as the new language. I then copied the new translation into the Localizable.strings file for russian.

I changed the language of my iPad to be russian, and everything is in Russian, except my application which is in English! I have deleted the app from the iPad and re-installed, cleaned the build and re-installed, and I can confirm that the localizable.strings file for russian is correctly copied into the application bundle.

I have tried these things with both UTF-8 and UTF-16 as the encoding of the files, and the translation keeps falling back to English. The original application worked with UTF-8.

Any ideas of how can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that iOS distinguishes general Russian localization and other russian localizations. I fell into the category of people mislead by Xcode's naming of the menus. Changing the localization to plain russian for all my localized files fixed the problem (it was RU-somethingelse).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but if others run into the same problem.  When changing your language on the iPad.  The first Russian looking language українська is actually Ukrainian.  The one you want it русский

Not sure if this was the case here but it's one I bumped into.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you already have Russian included in your localisations. Sometimes, some imported projects come with localisations, and they mess with your project's localisations.

Anyway, you need a generic Russian (ru) language. Not Russian-Ukraine (ru-UA) or Russian-Russia (ru-RU).